# How do I extends Chart in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am building a new type of Chart by extending `javafx.scene.chart.Chart`. I am testing a simple code by overriding `layoutChartChildren(double,double,double,double)`. Something like:

```
@Override
protected void layoutChartChildren(double top, double left, double contentWidth, double contentHeight) {

    double centreX = contentWidth/2 + left;
    double centreY = contentHeight/2 + top;

    Circle circle = new Circle();
    circle.setCenterX(centreX);
    circle.setCenterY(centreY);
    circle.setRadius(50.0f);
    circle.setFill(Color.BLUE);
}
```

However, when I put the chart into scene, nothing happens although debugging mode shows that the function has been called.
Anyone helps? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off extending XYChart which extends Chart.  LineChart extends XYChart and has much of the functionality built in by XYChart.  You can look at the source code to see how it's done.  [XYChart source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/88d3bef80ffc/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.java)